# Ember not able to enable/disable by validating email

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to validate an `email` address and accordingly enable or disable the action button. but it's not work. i am very new to `emberjs` any one please help me here? [Here is my Tutorial](http://yoember.com/)

html code ( hbs ) :

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Coming Soon</h1>

    <br/><br/>

    <p>Don't miss our launch date, request an invitation now.</p>

    <div class="form-horizontal form-group form-group-lg row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
            <input type="email" value=emailAddress class="form-control" placeholder="Please type your e-mail address." autofocus="autofocus"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" disabled={{isDisabled}} {{action 'saveInvitation'}}>Request invitation</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br/><br/>
</div>
```

controller js :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    emailAddress:'',
    isValid: Ember.computed.match('emailAddress', /^.+@.+\..+$/),
    isDisabled: Ember.computed.not('isValid'),
    actualEmailAddress: Ember.computed('emailAddress', function() {
        console.log('actualEmailAddress function is called: ', this.get('emailAddress'));
    }),
    emailAddressChanged: Ember.observer('emailAddress', function() {
        console.log('observer is called', this.get('emailAddress'));
    }),
    actions: {

        saveInvitation() {
            alert(`Saving of the following email address is in progress: ${this.get('emailAddress')}`);
            this.set('responseMessage', `Thank you! We've just saved your email address: ${this.get('emailAddress')}`);
            this.set('emailAddress', '');
        }
    }
});
```

when i enter the valid email, button not enables!!
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

In browser I am getting this error :

```
DEPRECATION: Usage of `router` is deprecated, use `_routerMicrolib` instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your case is you are using a pure html5 input that does not bind to the `emailAddress` attribute of the controller; that is even if you type to the input; the value of `emailAddress` will not change; which means the computed properties depending on `emailAddress` (`isValid`, `isDisabled`) will not be recalculated.

What should you do? You can use ember's input helper that performs a two-way binding and will make everything to work as expected. See the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a7cffb165d9d27575b90f55d8276b0f8?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) that shows both html5 input and ember's `input` helper (`{{input value=emailAddress ..}}`) together.

A few notes for you: If you insist on using an html input then you need to wrap the content to be bound to the controller within curly braces (`{{}}`). For instance; `<input value={{emailAddress}}/>` will bind the value of the `emailAddress` field to the input in a one-way fashion. You need to handle `change` event of input to reflect the value to `emailAddress` attribute by yourself if you use pure html5 input; but `input` helper of ember already makes a two-way binding and it is good enough for ember starters.

Another note is; I have seen you defined `actualEmailAddress` computed property; but it will never run! The reason is; computed properties will not run if they are not consumed (i.e. they are not bound to template); they are clever!

I did not go over the tutorial; but I would suggest finishing it from start to end to get clues of understanding what is going on. By the way; I do not know much about the deprecation warning you receive; but i can assure that it is not related with the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed information. I am just started the `ember` today. I am following the tutorial that's it.

Comment: that's great; have fun with ember :)

Comment: I am just start to learn Ember. can you recommend some good tutorials please?

Comment: I do not know anything other than the official guide's tutorial (which I do not like much personally :().